# Unity Object Pooling of gameObjects that have light maps and light probes baked

Tags: object, unity-game-engine, light, pooling, probe

Basically I m trying to develop an infinite running game for android and everything was working fine before I introduced light probes in my project. My idea is that I have 10 Tunnel-Shaped Sci-Fi Environment pieces with light maps baked for them and they are all lightmapped and i have placed them in a row that forms a long tunnel and then i m running my character in this tunnel and as soon as the character crosses a piece and the piece leaves the camera view, then i just teleport this piece to the last position of this tunnel (basically i m trying the object pooling technique to run my game smooth on mobile platform) and everything is working fine till here but now i want my moving character to receive lights and for this i used light probes and made a different light probe group for each and every piece of my environment but now my environment is moving but not the light probes and my character is losing its lighting Now

How to achieve dynamic lighting with baked lights for an infinite running along with object pooling?

Comment: as a general rule you NEVER pool in Unity these days.  just Instantiate. they fixed it so it works properly now (basically it pools for you).  I realize this is not relevant to your light probe issue.

Comment: Basically it is not the environment but the light probes are the reason for my problem, my environment is working properly (either i object-pool or instantiate) but my baked light probes are not moving with my environment, but i think i've found a solution, may be not the best, but it is somehow MAYBE working, light probe anchoring, as the lighting of my environment is not gonna change so i've just set the Anchor Override property of mesh renderer and getting my character lit up in a desired way ... BTW a big thanks to make me aware of the fact that instantiation has been fixed